# Reading multiple CSV files from a directory to check number of columns

Tags: python

I have a directory "D:\sta_times\data\Gen21\data_generation\csv_data" where I have 24 folders. viz. 'Apr2018', 'Apr2019', 'Aug2018', 'Aug2019', 'Dec2018', 'Dec2019', 'Feb2019', 'Feb2020', 'Jan2019', 'Jan2020', 'Jul2018', 'Jul2019', 'Jun2018', 'Jun2019', 'Mar2019', 'Mar2020', 'May2018', 'May2019', 'Nov2018', 'Nov2019', 'Oct2018', 'Oct2019', 'Sept2018', 'Sept2019'.

And I also have some csv files in each folder.

```
Eg: In 'Apr2018' there are 'Gen21_et_now.csv','Gen21_mirror_now.csv','Gen21_mnx.csv',
 'Gen21_mnx_hd.csv','Gen21_mn_plus.csv','Gen21_movies_now.csv','Gen21_movies_now_hd.csv',
'Gen21_romedy_now.csv','Gen21_romedy_now_hd.csv','Gen21_times_now.csv','Gen21_times_now_uk.csv',
 'Gen21_times_now_usa.csv','Gen21_times_now_world.csv','Gen21_zoom.csv','Gen21_zoom_usa.csv'
```

**There are 15 files in 'Apr2018' folder.**

I want to read each csv file from each folder and want to check the column number of each data frame.

I want to create a dictionary

```
{'Apr2018': {'Gen21_et_now': 69,
  'Gen21_mirror_now': 69,
  'Gen21_mnx': 68,
  'Gen21_mnx_hd': 68,
  'Gen21_mn_plus': 68,
  'Gen21_movies_now': 68,
  'Gen21_movies_now_hd': 68,...
 'Apr2019': {'Gen21_et_now': 69,
  'Gen21_mirror_now': 69,
  'Gen21_mnx': 68,...}
```

Where 'Apr2018' is the folder and 'Gen21_et_now' is the file and 69 is the number of columns present.

My code is

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(os.getcwd()+'\\csv_data')
month = {}
chnl_col = {}
for folder in range(len(os.listdir())):
    for file in range(len(os.listdir()[folder])):
        mydf=pd.read_csv(os.getcwd()+'\\'+os.listdir()[folder]+'\\'+os.listdir(os.listdir()[folder])[file])
        ch_data=os.listdir(os.listdir()[folder])[file].split('.')[0]
        chnl_col[ch_data]=len(mydf.columns)
    month[os.listdir()[folder]]=chnl_col
    chnl_col={}
```

After executing the code, **Only 7 files out of 15 files are being read**. and the output is

```
{'Apr2018': {'Gen21_et_now': 69,
  'Gen21_mirror_now': 69,
  'Gen21_mnx': 68,
  'Gen21_mnx_hd': 68,
  'Gen21_mn_plus': 68,
  'Gen21_movies_now': 68,
  'Gen21_movies_now_hd': 68},...}
```

Any kind help in this??

Comment: The last part of this line doesn't look correct:
`mydf=pd.read_csv(os.getcwd()+'\\'+os.listdir()[folder]+'\\'+os.listdir(os.listdir()[folder])[file])`

Comment: Try to use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), will make your code much readable

Comment: @archer If this line was incorrect then my dictionary wouldn't have created for a single csv file. Can you please specify the incorrect portion of the mentioned code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is at the line `for file in range(len(os.listdir()[folder])):` because `os.listdir()[folder]` is the name of the folder (a str) not the list of files inside the folder itself. So `len(os.listdir()[folder])` gives you the number of letters that you have in the name of your directory. You need to change your code like that :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
os.chdir(os.getcwd()+'\\csv_data')
month = {}
chnl_col = {}
for folder in range(len(os.listdir())):
    for file in range(len(os.listdir(path=os.getcwd()+'\\'+os.listdir()[folder]))):
        mydf=pd.read_csv(os.getcwd()+'\\'+os.listdir()[folder]+'\\'+os.listdir(os.listdir()[folder])[file])
        ch_data=os.listdir(os.listdir()[folder])[file].split('.')[0]
        chnl_col[ch_data]=len(mydf.columns)
    month[os.listdir()[folder]]=chnl_col
    chnl_col={}
```

I think that it would be good to improve the name of your variables : with the names `folder` and `file` we believe that you manipulate objects or names of object but in fact you manipulate indices.

Comment: You should also probably just avoid looping on indexes. Instead do for example `for folder in os.listdir()`